# Trouble reformatting JSON into an array for use in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Js has a built-in parse function which I am using: JSON.parse. It's the reformatting I'm having trouble wrapping my head around. Eg if I want to fetch all stars from the NASA API as JSON. This gives me a massive list of all the stars, with one entry looking like this:

```
{
    "absmag": 4.85, 
    "appmag": -26.72, 
    "colorb_v": 0.65, 
    "created_at": "2014-11-08T07:30:49.614Z", 
    "dcalc": 0.0, 
    "distly": 0.0, 
    "hipnum": 0.0, 
    "id": 1, 
    "label": "Sun", 
    "lum": 0.8913, 
    "plx": 0.0, 
    "plxerr": 0.0, 
    "speed": 0.0, 
    "texnum": 1.0, 
    "updated_at": "2014-11-08T07:30:49.614Z", 
    "vx": 0.0, 
    "vy": 0.0, 
    "vz": 0.0, 
    "x": 0.0, 
    "y": 0.0, 
    "z": 0.0
}
```

I then strip out just the "label" value for searching:

```
window.database.forEach(function(el) {
            var starNameArray = el.label;
        })
```

Which gives me a plain list of just the star labels. I need to convert this list to this form:

```
[ 'thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3' ]
```

I attempt to use something like this:

```
console.log("'" + starNameArray.join("','") + "'");
```

But I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: starNameArray.join is not a function"

Any idea why? Am I making a stupid mistake somewhere along the line here?

Answer (score 1):

```
var starNameArray = [];
window.database.forEach(function(el) {
   starNameArray.push(el.label);
});
console.log(starNameArray.join(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the code you provided `starNameArray` is just storing a string value have you tried creating an array and then pushing each label into the array like,

```
var starNameArray = [];
window.database.forEach(function(el){
     starNameArray.push(el.label);
})
```

after doing this you will have an array of the elements.

the `join` method will create a string of your elements rather than and actual array.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are declaring starNameArray inside the foreach and setting starNameArray to el.label, so its a string based on you JSON example. Also its scope is only inside the foreach so assuming your console.log is outside that function, and its not declared elsewhere, starNameArray would be undefined. @edrain just posted the code that fixes these issues.